# AS3 - Call function in root timeline from class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to call a function that is inside the root timeline of Flash from an external class.

This code is from the class:

```
private function loadImage(event:Event):void
{
    addToContainer()   
}
```

In the main timeline:

```
function addToContainer():void
{
    trace("Called")
}
```

How to manage that?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to put addToContainer() in the timeline?

I would consider removing your code entirely from the timeline, and creating a "Document class" with addToContainer in it instead.  That makes it easier to keep track of what you're looking at.

```
public class FunctionTest extends MovieClip {
   protected static var _this:FunctionTest;
   function FunctionTest() { _this = this; }
   public static function get application_root():FunctionTest { return _this; }
   public function addToContainer():void { trace("Called"); }
}
```

Now you have two ways of writing loadImage.  If it's within a DisplayObject (as per Marty Wallace's earlier comment), you can say something like

```
(this.root as FunctionTest).addToContainer();
```

If not, you have an alternative you can use from anywhere:

```
FunctionTest.application_root.addToContainer();
```

If you really have to define addToContainer() in the timeline, then you will need to initialize the external class with a link to the display root.  Do something like:

```
public class LoadImageClass {
   protected var _stored_root:MovieClip;
   function LoadImageClass(new_root:MovieClip) { this._stored_root = new_root; }
   public function loadImage():void {
      this._stored_root.addToContainer();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need to put addToContainer() in the timeline, sorry.

Comment: So then you will need to pass your external class a link to the display root.  I've updated my answer to give an example of how that might look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`MovieClip(root)`

to access the main timeline.

Comment: @Tom You'll need to make sure your class is a `DisplayObject` and is added to the stage for this to work. If neither of these are possible (your external class isn't using a DisplayObject as a base) then you'll need to pass reference to the main timeline or at least a DisplayObject elsewhere.

Comment: How do I make the class a DisplayObject ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to your object in the main timeline. When this event is triggered on your object, your function in the main timeline will be called.

```
//Main Timeline
var obj:YourExternalClass = new YourExternalClass();

obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addToContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and most simple way is to push the main timeline as a parameter in your class:

set a variable in your class:

```
public static var _this:Object;
```

now in your main timeline set this variable:

```
MyClass._this=this;
```

now in your class you have access to the main timeline using the `_this` variable:

```
_this.addToContainer()
```

I H☺P E this helps !