# Cannot convert root to movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, casting, root, movieclip, typeconverter

I have this code in a Movieclip that is called onto the stage in the main timeline

```
if(MovieClip(root).isWithinRange(MovieClip(e.currentTarget), MovieClip(root).hero,     10))
{
    if(e.currentTarget.getStatus() == 0)
    {
        e.currentTarget.unlock();
    }
}
```

And it gives me an error at MovieClip(root). I tried tracing that and it gave me the same error.

```
Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@4e131e9 to flash.display.MovieClip.
```

Tracing root gives me Object Stage.

So I can't convert the Stage object to a MovieClip, but when I try to skip the cast, it can't use the method because it says its a static type. How do I access this method?

Answer (score 0):

That is because stage is DisplayObject and not MovieClip. So you can convert it into MovieClip:

```
var stageRef:MovieClip = this.parent as MovieClip;
```

if object was placen on stage - **stage**.addChild(yourObject);

or you can acces it via DisplayObject (make sure to import flash.display.DisplayObject;)

```
DisplayOject(stage)["nameOfUrObject"];
```

Comment: The first one gave me null for stageRef.
If I'm going to try the second one, what is "nameOfUrObject"? The function I am trying to call or the root or e.currentTarget?

Comment: it is ur object. The one that u have placed into stage.

if nothing will work i will check it when i woke up.

Comment: So u can acces stage with DisplayObject(stage) and with DisplayOject(stage)["nameOfUrObject"] u can acces object placed into stage. Into [] just give its instance name.

Comment: the code is in the HomeRoom object. So I would write
    DisplayObject(stage)["HomeRoom"];
?

Answer (score 0):

The true answer here is that Stage IS NOT MovieClip. Period.

You cannot do what you wanted to do and I clearly can't understand where this `isWithinRange` method came from? If you want answers, ask specific questions. I already answered this one, unfortunately it won't help you much :)

p.s.
After reading all comments - here's a link that may help you: [AS3 - Call function in root timeline from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437452/as3-call-function-in-root-timeline-from-class)

Keeping everything on timeline is a very very bad approach (sorry to say it).

Comment: I can't access methods on the main timeline??
isWithinRange is a method in the first layer on the main timeline

Comment: I would love to use classes, but we don't do that in this flash course